# MPMoviePlayerController not playing .wmv

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am using MPMoviePlayerController in a pretty standard way.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [self.movieController moviePlayer];        
player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[player play]
```

I am playing videos and it works. However, I am not able to play wmv videos. It keeps saying "Loading". The video works well on my OSX.

Is wmv format supported? What is the problem here?

Comment: I don't think iOS supports WMV.

Comment: You know something, MPMoviePlayerController is not a view controller and you should never treat it like one. It inherits from NSObject class. You would not need much to work with movieController. Just initialize movieController with proper url; add it to your view and just invoke play. That should do it.

Comment: iOS doesn't support WMV. Why would it?

Comment: Do you know a library that does support wmv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS supports only the following video containers:

- .mov
- .m4v
- .mp4
- .3gp

So .wmv files can't be played. I'd be surprised if they could, given that it's a Microsoft invention.

More info at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html